# Simplify a summation formula with known identity

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I can calculate the formula:
$$\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^{m-1}\lfloor \frac{i\ n_1 +j\ n_2}{m}\rfloor$$
with Hermite identity:
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\lfloor\frac{j\ n}{m}+x\rfloor=\lfloor m x\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}(m-1)(n-1)$$
$$\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^{m-1}\lfloor \frac{i\ n_1 +j\ n_2}{m}\rfloor=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}(in_1 +\frac{1}{2}(n_2-1)(m-1))=\frac{1}{2}m(m-1)(n_1 +n_2-1)$$

However, when I want to simplify this formula with Mathematica input

```
FullSimplify[Sum[Floor[(i n_1+j n_2)/m],{i,0,m-1},{j,0,m-1}]]
```

it doesn't work and returns

[image]

How can I simplify this formula with Mathematica?

Comment: You Can't.  Mathematica is not a `magic box` that'll spit out a solution to `any` problem.

Comment: Really? Can I somehow tell it to simplify in a way that it can simplify?

Comment: Only `50 %` can: `Sum[Floor[(i n1 + j n2)/m], {i, 0, m - 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n1 \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
   n2 \[Element] PositiveIntegers, m \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
   j \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]` gives the answer.

Comment: ! Thank you！I found ```Sum[Sum[Floor[(i n1 + j n2)/m], {i, 0, m - 1},   Assumptions -> {n1 \[Element] PositiveIntegers,     n2 \[Element] PositiveIntegers, m \[Element] PositiveIntegers,     j \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]/.GCD[m,n1]->1/.Floor[j n2]->j n2,{j,0,m-1}]``` can give the answer1